# Keep floating divs on same line

Tags: html, css, css-float

How do i keep two elements in the same row with fixed right column?
I want right div to be with fixed size, and left column fluid, but when in insert long text to left one, then right one goes to the next column..

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Jbbxk/2/

Is there any pure CSS solutions?

**NB! Wrap div must have dynamic width!**
For demostration purposes it has fixed witdh, so it will wrap.

Cheers!

Comment: Your wrapper has a fixed width. What do you expect??? Or am I missing something? Overflow?

Comment: My wrapper in demo has fixed width, but in my applicatication is has relative width(50%). An container size changes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is one common way of doing what you want:

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    background-color: #CCC;
    margin-right: 48px;
}
.right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background-color: #888;
}
```

Explanation:

- The **fluid left column** fills the whole width but saves space for the right column with `margin-right: [right column width];`
- The **fixed right column** is placed at an absolute position at top 0, right 0 (its correct place)
- The **wrap div** is assigned `position: relative` so the right column position is determined according to it.

Comment: That is exctly what i'm looking for!

Answer (score 8):

It's actually easier than I thought, just remove the float:left; from the left class and put your right floating items above them in the HTML

[update fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jbbxk/13/)

Comment: Sry, better solution by @pacha

Comment: This is a very sleek solution. However, the content of the left column (the fluid one) may end up under the right one when the right one is shorter in height which may or may not be what you want...

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution. Set `display: table-cell;`

http://jsfiddle.net/Jbbxk/54/

```
.left {
    /*display: left;*/
    display: table-cell;
}
.right {
    float: right;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Also, the floating div comes first:

```
<div class="right">
    &nbsp;
</div>
<div class="left">
    Looooooooong content - pushes right to next row<br>
    NOT OK
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
.left {
    max-width: 152px;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that will work as in his stylesheet it says that the width of the wrap div is dynamic.

Comment: @32bitfloat Yes, thats for demostration, actually in my app it is 50%, so its changing

Answer (score 0):

as you have dynamics width, use % like

```
.left {
float: left;
background-color: #CCC;
width:75%;
}
```

I have updated the fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/Jbbxk/6/

Comment: Nice, you understanded what i want, but this way when wrap div is 500px there's alot of white space between divs