# How to keep two dynamic divs on same line and force to word wrap on right

Tags: html, css

What I need to do is to keep two dynamic divs on the same horizontal line and force the rightmost div to word wrap its text rather than moving to the next row.

I've tried numerous approaches such as the ones in this similar, but not identical, question:

[Keep floating divs on same line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450962/keep-floating-divs-on-same-line)

Here is a very simplified version of what I want with my experimental solutions stripped out (such as using table-cells, float right on the right div, etc.):

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='images'>
    images 
</div>
<div class='text'>
    long text long text long text long text long text  long text long text long text long text long text
</div>
</div>

.images {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
}

.text {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
}
```

In this code I need the alignment to happen correctly even if Javascript does not load so coming back and fixing it with jQuery is not an option.  Both divs are dynamic, they can change width based on user interaction.

I can get the two divs to align if the text in the second div is not too long, but if I shrink the browser window until its too tight then the second div jumps to the second line.

I want the text to be left aligned, so the second div text should line up to the right side of the first div.

The divs are also not the same height, nor is the height fixed, it can very depending on content of the page.

Obviously one solution would be to use the table tag but I hope to avoid this as tables are not generally a best practice.

Update:
For the sake of completeness, here is a fiddle which is much closer to my actual page format -- images on the left, on the right long text and a stack of buttons under the text.  https://jsfiddle.net/yyt0tkLr/  Currently I'm trying to get the stack of buttons to show up on a separate line without using a br tag to do it.

Comment: You could use flexbox. It has good support these days. But why not just use table-cell/table CSS selectors? They were created for a reason. Get over the superstrict semantic use of elements. Sometimes you've got to just use what CSS gives you. This is one of those times.

Comment: @PaulM -- I actually have used the table-cell/table CSS selectors but they aren't solving the problem for me in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason you can't use a float as nature intended?

**[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/bwkLawpe/)**

```css
.images {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
}
.text {
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='text'>
    <div class='images'>images</div>

    long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using `display:inline` for the right div?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fe6yp0m1/

Comment: yes I did try using display:inline, I see that it works on my trimmed example here but did not work on the more complex actual code for some reason that I don't yet understand.  Still, worthy of an upvote though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best and proper way to do it is using clear after the use of float element else your wrapper will not be useful Below is my way of doing it please check

```
.images {
    border:1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
    float:left;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
.text {
    display:inline;    
    border:1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Siddharth_Pandey/6vb4bkng/

Comment: I actually did try this on my actual page (not the reduced version) and could not get it to work either.

Answer (score 0):

If you give your divs a width attribute, it all comes together. Without it, the divs will collide and you'll have one wrap under the other.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='images'>
    images 
</div>
<div class='text'>
    long text long text long text long text long text  long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text  long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text  long text long text long text long text long text
</div>
</div>

.images {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    height: 200px;
    width:20%;
}

.text {
    float:left;
    border:1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    width:75%
}

.wrapper {
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Ls3bw80t/

Comment: OP says the divs are "dynamic". I take that to mean their widths can vary.

Comment: Correct, adding in even a percentile makes them "dynamic" as they will adjust on the fly. If you really want to get into it, there should be a min and max width set if he plans to structure the divs this way.

Comment: Although I could probably set a min and max width for these divs, I don't think my solution can depend on that.  Besides, I really don't think it should be necessary.   Nice try though!